# Combine local and Google colab resources OR avoid excessive memory usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I have seen a lot of posts asking how to connect Collab to your local machine. However, it was not clear to me if it's possible to combine the resources from the [documentation](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html).

Let's say that my model needs 35GB RAM and I can only use up to 25 from Collab. Is there any way one could use the remaining 10GB from my laptop?

In case that's not possible, the problem I am trying to resolve is converting a set of documents to the corresponding numerical form using word embeddings, such as GloVe using the following code:

```
def convert_docs_to_embeddings(corpus, word_dict, dim_size):
  tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=40000)
  tokenizer.fit_on_texts(corpus)
  
  max_words_text = max(corpus, key=lambda sentence: len(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence, language='portuguese')))
  max_sentence_len = len(nltk.word_tokenize(max_words_text, language='portuguese'))
  vocab_len = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

  docs = np.zeros((len(corpus), vocab_len, dim_size))
  
  for index, doc in enumerate(corpus):
    current_doc = np.zeros((vocab_len, dim_size))
    for word in doc.split(' '):
      embedding_vector = word_dict.get(word)
      if word.isalnum() and embedding_vector is not None and embedding_vector.any():
        idx = tokenizer.word_index[word]
        current_doc[idx] = embedding_vector[:dim_size]
    docs[index] = current_doc
  return docs
```

The piece of code itself may be off-topic, I can write a new question to identify solutions at the code level if needed. With smaller datasets, the code works fine, but when I try to use a medium-sized (3000 examples) with larger vocabulary it becomes a problem